# I cant start Android studio application , It seems like resolve error

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

When I create new Android project on Android studio , It will display an error message, that also shown below.

```
Failed to import new Gradle project: Could not install Gradle distribution from 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.6-bin.zip'.
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
error in opening zip file

Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)
```

Comment: this question was asked and answered dozens of times

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if it will help a lot or not but:

- at my work there is a proxy, even if intellyJ-Idea think it can access the internet I stuck on the same error upon creating a project.
- It's a problem I never have experienced from home, where I have no proxy.

So maybe your problem is just a proxy And/or firewall one ;).

*edit: I implicitly assumed you have first tried what is in comments.*